# ASP.net for multi user communal applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, theory

I'm hoping this is a good place to post this question, its more around theory than actual code. Please bear with me.

I have coded many C# and Java applications both for fun and for work, but have no background with web based languages such as asp.

I need to write a web based application which will have features such as games (simple games like tic tac toe) which users can play against each other and a chat feature.

If I were to use ASP.net for this, do I still need to write a server back-end for the users to connect to, or can this run nativity inside the asp.net (with C#) pages?

Or is ASP perhaps not the best language to be doing this in?

Comment: Oh just FYI, this won't be public internet facing, the system will exist on it's own private LAN, so I will have full control over the client devices as well as the server.

Comment: If you just need locally executed C# code and are familiar with building WPF or Windows Forms apps, you might consider Silverlight.   aASP.NET requires HTML and JavaScript knowlwdge for client side logic. The C# only executes on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET is a server-side language. The client (a browser I am guessing) doesn't run anything other than JavaScript at the moment.

If you are familiar with C#, then you can use ASP.NET with C# on the backend server. For a chat application check the [sample SignalR app in the getting started guide](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20). For tic tac toe, you probably [can code the whole thing on the client side using JavaScript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/tactoe.shtml). Unless if you want multiple players for one tic tac toe game then you can use a SignalR component to communicate between them.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need. I hate asking really basic questions such as this! The games will all be 2 player across the lan so I'll look into that singnalR for that too.